# Why does my new lamp hum while turned off?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I just changed the ceiling lamp I had in my kitchen, from an ancient one (probably more than 20+ years old) to new and beautiful hanging one. I also switched from the old incandescent bulb to a CFL. Now  the problem is that the lamp has a very low hum when it is turned off - and the humming stops when i turn it on. The lamp isn't on a dimmer switch (which wouldn't explain why it hums while turned off anyway).

Comment: I would suggest that you try several things. First swap out the CFL to see if the problem persists. Then temporarily swap in an incandescent bulb to see if it hums with that.

Comment: If the lamp is connected to an electronic dimmer, timer, or other device, the hum could possibly be explained by the fact that these devices can "leak" current.  Since some fancier controls require power to operate; and a grounded (neutral) conductor is not always present, these devices sometimes use a bit of electricity and "leak" current through the switch. It's not enough power to light the lamp, but might be just enough to make it hum (especially with energy saving bulbs, since they require less power to operate).

Comment: Is the lamp controlled by a single conventional wall switch (only two wires on the switch and possibly a third bare or green ground wire)?